Help identifying a rare version of Fiend Folio
I was trying to identify an old "monster manual"-like book (with ~64/96 pages)
called "Fiend Folio":
an old friend of mine lent it to me  about 30 years ago
for a few days, so I vaguely remember its cover to be quite dark with some reddish monster (maybe a demon or devil?  but it is not the same cover of the ad&d player handbook)
If I google for "fiend folio cover" I can see only one manual with that name and it has a colorful  Githyanki on the cover, and definitely it is not that one - moreover I remember the graphic style was less amateur / more professional.
I am almost sure it was a manual for ADnD 2ed - I was told that maybe it could be the UK version of the US manual, with just a different cover, but I doubt it

Is there a chance you're mixing up books in your memory? Your description is spot on for the Advanced D&D Dungeon Masters Guide.

I surrender: no info can be found about it - so I must conclude that my memory was failing me...

Is this what you remember?

It looks like an alternate cover that was never officially used, even though it was created for the original Fiend Folio (for AD&D 1E though, not 2E). The original Fiend Folio sold poorly though, so they didn't bother with an updated version. Some people used it for third-party reprints of the Fiend Folio, and your friend may have had one of those.
Note: It's still a githyanki on the cover AFAICT, but it's a different look from how githyanki are portrayed in later materials, so it's hard to recognize.
The only alternatives I know of are:

The 2E Monstrous Compendium Fiend Folio (not it, the cover color is white, with three different monsters, doesn't match description), and
The 3E Fiend Folio, but while that one has a red color scheme, it doesn't have any obvious monsters on the cover, so it's unlikely to be the one you're thinking of.


thanks for your answer
unfortunately none of these seem to fit...

Note that this artwork was re-purposed for 2e Tales of the Outer Planes

What you describe sounds like a copy of 1E's "Manual of the Planes." Does this look familiar?


unfortunately I am almost sure the manual name was "Fiend Folio"...

Maybe this one?
Fiend Folio: Appendix, Monstrous Compendium (Advanced Dungeons & Dragons, 2nd Edition)

It checks that the Title prominently displays Fiend Folio (with a smaller "Appendix" beneath), that it is 2nd Edition, and that it sports a reddish creature.
It however wasn't a bound book, it contained ring-binder punched pages. That was how the Monster Manual (then called "Monstrous Compendium") was set up in second Edition initially.  I think the pitch was that it made it easier to manage a binder of just the monsters you needed, and that it allowed you to take the monsters which you needed out and put up behind the DM screen.

This is the one any only Fiend Folio for 2nd edition so I suspect it's the right one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiend_Folio#Advanced_Dungeons_&_Dragons_2nd_edition

@JollyJoker: This assumes the OP is correct that it was actually from 2E. 30 years ago would be in the 2E era, but they could easily have seen a 1E book and misremembered.

I am afraid that my memory is failing me...  ok, now I have asked an old friend that used to play DnD with us back in the days if, by any chance, he remembers any further details on that manual...  cross fingers
